# how to read correct pixels from windows clipboard copy image?

Tags: windows, bitmap, clipboard

i'm using this:

```
GetClipboardData(CF_DIB);
```

i view it as a BITMAPINFOHEADER and take into account

1. biWidth
2. biHeight
3. biBitCount 24 vs 32
4. if biCompression is BI_BITFIELDS then i skip over the first 3*4 bytes of the pixel data.

most of the time when i copy an image i can get the pixel data from it just fine. but when copying from certain applications like Telegram, sometimes the colors are messed up, sometimes the image is skewed, all sorts of crazy artifacts happen when trying to view the clipboard image. i don't see anything special in the BITMAPINFOHEADER of these images i'm rendering incorrectly. what could i possibly be forgetting to handle?

Comment: Maybe you're misinterpreting the data. Did you know each row is padded to a multiple of 4 bytes? It will only make a difference if the width isn't evenly divisible by 4.

Comment: @MarkRansom this is very promising! only matters if width isn't multiple of 4 and biBitCount isn't 32. it looks like that's where all my issues are. instead of trying to figure out how to remove the padding i'll probably just rewrite the data from 24bit to 32bit filling alpha with 255

Comment: @MarkRansom post this as the answer so i can mark it as the solution. i was struggling with this issue for months, even chatGPT wasn't aware of this padding :( ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little-known fact about Microsoft bitmaps is that every row is padded to an even multiple of 4 bytes.  It is natural to assume that one row follows the next immediately, but there may be 1 to 3 bytes of padding on each row that will throw your alignment off.  You will see this as colors that aren't what they should be, or a skewed image as each row is shifted from its proper position.

If your pixels are all 4 bytes (RGBA) or your image width is a multiple of 4 (more common than random chance would suggest) each row will already be a multiple of 4 bytes, and you won't notice a problem.